# $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has $n$ different rows and $\operatorname{rank} B = n-1$. Is any selection of $n-1$ rows of $B$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a square matrix with $\operatorname{rank} B=n-1$ and $n$ different rows with at least one non-zero entry. Is it true, that any selection of $n-1$ rows of $B$ is linearly independent?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider the first and third rows of $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Sorry! In my question, I missed the condition, that any row has at least one non-zero entry. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Huh? It's not true that any row has at least one non-zero entry, nor do I see why it matters

Comment: For example, the matrix could have the first n-2 rows independent and the last two rows the same.  In that case, any n-1 rows that happen to contain the last to will be dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 10
\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 10
\\
7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank 3.  But omit the last row; the remaining rows are linearly dependent (row $2$ is the average of rows $1$ and $3$).

Comment: What we can say is: if $A$ has rank $n-1$, then there is **some** choice of $n-1$ rows which are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you. We can also say, that at least one row is a linear combination of the other ones, right?